# Scrapy persistent cache

Tags: caching, scrapy

We need to be able to re-crawl historical data. Imagine today is 23rd of June. We crawl a website today but after a few days we realize we have to re-crawl it, "seeing" it exactly as it was on 23rd. That means, including all possible redirects, GET and POST requests etc. ALL the pages the spider sees, should be exactly as they were on 23rd, no matter what.

Use-case: if there is a change in the website, and our spider is unable to crawl something, we want to be able to get back "in the past" and re-run the spider after we fix it.

Generally, this should be quite easy - subclass the standard Scrapy's cache, force it to use dates for subfolders and have something like that:

`cache/spider_name/2015-06-23/HERE ARE THE CACHED DIRS`

but when I was experimenting with this, I realized sometimes the spider crawls the *live* website. That means, it doesn't take some pages from the cache (though the appropriate files exist on the disk) but instead it takes them from the live website. It happened with pages with captchas, in particular, but maybe with some other ones.

**How can we force Scrapy to *always* take the page from the cache, not hitting the live website at all? Ideally, it should even work with no internet connection.**

Update: we've used the Dummy policy and HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

To do exactly what you want you should had this in your settings:

HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_MISSING = True

*Then if enabled, requests not found in the cache will be ignored instead of downloaded.*

When you are setting :
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0

It only assure you that "*cached requests will never expire*" , but if a page isn't in your cache, then it will be download.

You can check the [documentation.](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-ignore-missing)